# Throw 404 for a html page

Tags: c#, webforms, http-status-code-404

I have customs errors in my web config redirecting pages like this

```
www.mysite.co.uk/idontexist
```

to a 404 page I have created, which works fine. If I stick `.html` on the end of any url im getting a diiferent error page telling me this resource doesnt exist. How can still throw a 404 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx) might help. i don't know if it's the only way.

Comment: I suspect that the issue may be that www.mysite.co.uk/idontexist is being handled by ASP.NET and as such your CustomErrors rules will come into play, however your IIS config may be excluding html files from being processed by by ASP.NET and so the standard 404 page is served instead.

If the link provided by wazz doesn't help, let me know and Ill post some details on what it might be.

Comment: Cheers thanks for your help guys but as it turns out the methods that I was trying worked but <CustomErrors> in my webconfig was set as DetailedLocalOnly which means it is going to show the IIS 404 on my local machine, I changed this to custom and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set specific pages for error codes like 404 in the web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errorPages/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

That will allow you to redirect to your custom page.